# Not able to connect to Cassandra using cqlsh, getting ConnectionRefusedError

Tags: cassandra

I have installed the Cassandra and not able to connect using `cqlsh`:

```
[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ which cassandra 
/usr/sbin/cassandra
[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ cassandra -v
4.0.5
[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ sudo systemctl status cassandra.service
Active: active (running)

[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ grep rpc_address /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
rpc_address: 192.168.56.9
```

```
[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ sudo cqlsh 192.168.56.9 9042 -u cassandra -p cassandra 
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.56.9:9042': 
ConnectionRefusedError(111,  "Tried connecting to [('192.168.56.9', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

```
[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ netstat -an | grep 9042
```

```
[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ telnet 192.168.56.9 9042 
Trying 192.168.56.9... telnet: connect to address 192.168.56.9: Connection refused
```

How can I connect? Is there anything else I can try?

I am trying the nodetool from the same node

```
[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load        Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID  Rack 
UN  192.168.56.9  168.15 KiB  16      100.0%                     rack1

[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ sudo cqlsh 192.168.56.9 9042 -u cassandra -p cassandra
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.56.9:9042': ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.56.9', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})

[cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ grep _address /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml | grep -v '#'
listen_address: 192.168.56.9
rpc_address: 192.168.56.9
```

Comment: Does `nodetool status` show the same IP or a different one?

Comment: Thanks for the help , please see below. [cassandra@linuxdr ~]$ sudo nodetool status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.

Comment: Are you running nodetool on the same machine that's running Cassandra?  Also, adjust your grep above and try this: `grep _address /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml | grep -v "#"`. What other IPs do you see?

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms you described indicate that the node is not listening for client connections on port `9042`. Cassandra is running in a sort of degraded mode so despite showing as "up" and "normal" (`UN` in `nodetool status` output), the client native transport (CQL binary protocol) is disabled.

It is simple to verify whether the Cassandra process is listening for client connections on port `9042` using Linux utilities like `lsof` or `netstat`:

```
$ sudo lsof -nPi -sTCP:LISTEN
```

```
$ sudo netstat -tnlp
```

This can happen if someone ran `nodetool drain` on the node (status will be listed as `DRAINED` in the `nodetool netstats` output), or if someone ran `nodetool disablebinary`.

In the worst case, if the node encountered some form of disk failure then it would have triggered Cassandra to go into maintenance mode where both gossip (port `7000` by default) and native transport are stopped but the process is still running so can be interrogated via JMX (the `nodetool` utility connects via JMX).

You will need to review the Cassandra logs (default location is `/var/log/cassandra`), going through the warnings and/or errors for clues as to why you can't connect. Cheers!

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!